# Rails: Customizing an infowindow using gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, customization, infowindow, gmaps4rails

I have been following the gmaps4rails tutorials on github but am not understanding how to customize the infowindow. I have a database that is collecting internship data including locations, names, companies, and descriptions. The markers are appearing on the correct places on the map, however I can only get the infowindow to display the name or the description or the company when I need it to display all of them.

I am new to rails, and do not totally understand what I need to be updating to allow all of these attributes to appear in the infowindow. I am attaching my code below:

Internship model:

```
class Internship < ApplicationRecord
    geocoded_by :address
    after_validation :geocode
end
```

Internship View:

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBj4qLUeW291Z5WvVOwzseQONRBGCnA8ds"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/master/dist/markerclusterer.min.js"></script>
<script src='//cdn.rawgit.com/printercu/google-maps-utility-library-v3-read-only/master/infobox/src/infobox_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script> <!-- only if you need custom infoboxes -->
<div style='width: 800px;'>
   <div id="map" style='width: 1100px; height: 600px'></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
   handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
   markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
   handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
   handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
</script>
```

Internship Controller:

```
def index
  @internships = Internship.all
  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@internships) do |internship, marker|
  marker.lat internship.latitude
  marker.lng internship.longitude
  marker.infowindow internship.description
  end
end
```

Any help I can get is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add an array to the controller that holds all the values from the database and then passes the array into the infowindow:

```
  def index
    @internships = Internship.all

    @internship_properties = Array.new
    @internships.each do |internship|
    @internship_properties.push(internship)
  end


 @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@internship_properties) do |internship_prop, marker|
  concat_info_window = "#{internship_prop.name}, #{internship_prop.address}, #{internship_prop.company}, #{internship_prop.title}, #{internship_prop.date}, #{internship_prop.description}"
  marker.lat internship_prop.latitude
  marker.lng internship_prop.longitude
  marker.infowindow concat_info_window

 end
end
```